# How can I extract location hierarchy from Openstreetmap?

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, openstreetmap

I need to store first parent of any Location entity in a mySQL database. So at the end I'll have a complete hierarchy. For example I need to know Berlin is part of Germany and store Germany as first parent of Berlin in the table. How can I query OSM for such information?

Comment: Any luck on creating the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query OSM directly for this information. Of course OSM contains such information, mainly through [boundary relations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative) and [admin_level](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative#admin_level)s. But the exact hierarchy between different elements has to be calculated first.

[Geocoders for OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geocoding) can be used to obtain these information. The currently most popular one is [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). You can [install your own Nominatim instace](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) by either importing the whole [planet](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) or an [country or area extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Then you can try to obtain these information via the database created by Nominatim.

Comment: I took a look at Nominatim and it seems that it doesn't really support mac, is there a solution for mac?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea :( You can take a look at the other geocoders, or run Nominatim inside a virtual machine.